Is there a way to bypass deletion error of non-empty directories?
I am currently testing a code that creates a folder with some files every time I run it. I cannot rerun since it cannot write to a folder that already exists.
When I try deleting the entire folder, I get this message
"Deletion failed
Directory "tridesclous2_output" is not empty. Only empty directories can be deleted"
If I delete the subfiles within the folder, I am able to delete the file, but it can be lengthy based on how many files are within the folder. Is there a way to delete the entire folder including its subfolders and files?

what are you using to delete file? Can you share some code sample that describe what you are doing? (If not running at all pseudocode will do)

Just use a command line process to delete everything. It will depend on what system you are on, but you can absolutely write a command line command that deletes with no discretion.
